# Which is better: A new controller to send POST arguments or use the current one? Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework, soap

> [What type of API is this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578823/what-type-of-api-is-this)

This is a followup question regarding an API question I had.

I am using Zend Framework 2.

```
zf-skeleton/module/MyApplication/src/MyApplication/Controller/IndexController.php

public function submitAction() {
     $myForm = new MyForm();
     $myForm->get('submit')->setValue('Add');         

     $request = $this->getRequest();
     if ($request->isPost()) {
     $myModel = new MyModel();
     $myForm->setInputFilter($myModel->getInputFilter());
     $myForm->setData($request->getPost());

     if ($myForm->isValid()) {
         // Form is validated. [1]
```

Now the form is validated, do I send the `POST` arguments to another action within this controller or create a new controller?

I am looking for best practices.

Comment: You should be looking into services. Controller methods shouldn't be calling other controller's methods.

Comment: @beingalex for this you can use controller plugin

Comment: I think Alex Tartan has nailed it. http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/in-depth-guide/services-and-servicemanager.html

Answer (score 0):

As for best practices,
In a **small scale application** , it would be unwise to create a new controller.
But when we talk about a large scale application, each piece is done seperately, and new controller is recommended. 
So, it totally depends on your application.

Comment: If I create a new method in my `IndexController`  called `'soapAction'` for a small scale application that would be ok?

Comment: A few more details would be helpful, but what you are saying right now is much feasible. Yeah, no need to make controller , first try through this.

Answer (score 0):

never use controller inside a controller.
if you want to share a common method in multiple controllers you must create a component(for cakephp framework) or a controller plugin (for zend). visit http://lab.empirio.no/custom-controller-plugin-in-zf2.html